# Span-within-a-span background color precedence

Tags: html, css, background-color

See http://i40.tinypic.com/2nv4gol.png for example image.

I have a span element (blue background in example image) that contains other span elements (red background in example image). Currently, the inner spans' red background color take precedence over the container span's blue background color.

I need the container span's blue background color to take precedence over the inner spans' red background color.

Can I do something with the container span's z-index and fiddle its opacity? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can define a new css for the inner spans, make it transparent background and add a !important to the CSS rule, like, if the inner spans are class 'x' ...
`.x {background-color:transparent !important}`

Comment: Thanks, that, with a combination of JS add/remove class worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try setting the container to `position: relative; z-index: 1;` and the inner ones to `position: relative; z-index: 0;`, but I think that would hide the text behind the background colour too.

I think more information on why you are trying to do this would help give a better answer than this, but maybe you could have some JavaScript remove the background colour of the inner spans? Like I said, it depends on what you're doing, exactly.

Comment: I tried the position:relative + z-index trick, and no change in my result. Still the inner spans background take precedence over the container span. 

This is for a Rich Text Editor, so some JS to remove the background color of the inner spans would be a pain, as I'd have to store which inner spans had what background colors and reapply them after I deselect the text...